# Graph API facebook. How to get friend lists?

Tags: android, facebook, api, for-loop

```
Session.openActiveSession(MainActivity.this, true, permissions,

            new Session.StatusCallback() {

                // callback when session changes state
                @Override
                public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                        Exception exception) {
                    if (session.isOpened()) {

                        Request.newMeRequest(session,
                                new GraphUserCallback() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                            Response response) {
                                        if (user != null) {
                                            TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                                            welcome.setText("Hello "
                                                    + user.getName() + "!");
                                        }

                                    }
                                }).executeAsync();


                        // make request to the /me API
                        // when i add this code, it's crash

                        new Request(session, "/me", null,
                                HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
                                    public void onCompleted(
                                            Response response) {
                                        Toast.makeText(
                                                getApplicationContext(),
                                                response.getGraphObjectList()
                                                        .size()
                                                        + "",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
                        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, null);

                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Crashes? Do you get a stacktrace?

Answer (score 2):

it worked for me.this is for those who wanted show fb friendlist in a listview or to get friendslist without dialog

```
    final Session sessionfb = ParseFacebookUtils.getSession();// user facebook session.
       List<String> permissions = sessionfb.getPermissions();

            if (!permissions.contains("user_friends")) {

                Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new   Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                        FlyTags.this, Arrays.asList("user_friends"))
                        .setCallback(newPermissionsCallback).setRequestCode(1);

                sessionfb.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
} else
{
        requestFacebookFriends(sessionfb);

}
```

// add onanctivityResult and NewPermissionsRequest  to get the respective permission and return a session to above method .

**requestFacebookFriends(sessionfb);**

```
private void requestFacebookFriends(Session session2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Request friendsRequest = createRequest(session);
    friendsRequest.setCallback(new Request.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
```

// do whatever you want ... 
                List friends = getResults(response);//fbgraph list users 
                parseUserFromFQLResponse(response);//json method

```
        }
    });
    friendsRequest.executeAsync();

}
```

**createRequest**

```
private Request createRequest(Session session2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Request request = Request.newGraphPathRequest(session, "me/friends",
                null);

        Set<String> fields = new HashSet<String>();
        String[] requiredFields = new String[] { "id", "name", "picture" };
        fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(requiredFields));

        Bundle parameters = request.getParameters();
        parameters.putString("fields", TextUtils.join(",", fields));
        request.setParameters(parameters);

        return request;
    }
```

**parseUserFromFQLResponse(Response response)**

```
protected void parseUserFromFQLResponse(Response response) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        GraphObject go = response.getGraphObject();
        JSONObject jso = go.getInnerJSONObject();
        JSONArray arr = jso.getJSONArray("data");

        for (int i = 0; i < (arr.length()); i++) {
            JSONObject json_obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
            FbFriend fbobject = new FbFriend();// object class 
            String id = json_obj.getString("id");
            fbobject.uid = id;
            String name = json_obj.getString("name");
            fbobject.name = name;
            String urlImg =   json_obj.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url");

            fbobject.pictureUrl = urlImg;

            friendslist.add(fbobject);// friendslist is arralist of Fbfriend 
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**as graph result**

```
 protected List<GraphUser> getResults(Response response) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            GraphMultiResult multiResult = response
                    .getGraphObjectAs(GraphMultiResult.class);
            GraphObjectList<GraphObject> data = multiResult.getData();
            return data.castToListOf(GraphUser.class);
        }
```